# showing undefined value in changing reducer state value from action payload

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to change reducer state value from action payload but not able to dot that as its showing undefined value. Please suggest on it

```
//Action file

import * as actionTypes from './actions';

export const counterReducer = ({ name = 'test' }) => {

    return {
        type: actionTypes.INCREMENT,
        data: name
    }
}

import * as actionTypes from './actions';

const initialState = {
    counter: 0,
    mydata: 'my Name is'
};

//Reducer File

const counterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.INCREMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter + 1,
                mydata: action.data
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default counterReducer;
```

Comment: Can you show where you are calling the function which increments state?

Comment: yes sure


 <Button onClick={this.props.counterAction}>                  
                    Counter: {this.props.counterProp}
</Button>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        counterProp: state.counterReducer.counter,
        mydataProp: state.counterReducer.mydata
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        counterAction: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.INCREMENT })
    }
}

Comment: Hello ! 
You should try using redux-thunk to access the previous state in the reducer
cf: [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

Comment: but why is not possible here? any specific reason.

Comment: @AndréGomes no.

Comment: no-one here to solve my problem.? why this problem coming..?